# Fastlane SwiftPM dependency caching

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, continuous-deployment, fastlane, swiftpm

SwiftPM is always fetching modules whenever I deploy a build. This takes a long time. I use Fastlane on GitHub for our CI/CD. May be there is some way to enable packages caching?

Looks like [GitHub do not provide caching](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows) for Swift packages.